# Angularjs populate Bootstrap Dropdown dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am trying to build the bootstrap dropdown-menu element dynamically once a function has returned the data that I want to display in the menu (using AngularUI).

In the application that I am working on, I have to initialize the request for the data, and then a different function is triggered when the data is returned. So I tried to progmatically open the dropdown-menu from the second function like this:

In my Angularjs Controller:

```
// This is the function that is triggered by the button to open the menu:    
$scope.getData = function(owner){
        API.getData(owner);
    }


    // This is the function that is triggered by the thirdparty API, and contains the data for the menu
        $scope.returnedData = function(owner, data){
            for (var n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
                $scope.menuItems.push(data[i]);
            }
            $scope.$apply();

            for(var s = 0; s < $scope.schema.length; s++){
                if($scope.schema[s].owner == owner){
                    console.log('opening menu');
                    $scope.schema[s].menu = true; // <-- Here I open the menu
                }
            }

            $scope.$apply();

        }
```

And this is the html to display the dropdown-menu:

```
<div class="round-button" id="menu{{$index}}" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getData(module.owner)">
  <a href="#">+</a>
</div>

<div dropdown is-open="module.menu">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu{{$index}}">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#">item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The dropdown-menu opens successfully but there are no items.

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to get this to work. TIA!

Comment: You probably need to do this in a directive as you might need to 'refresh/reload' the dropdown

Comment: Use the ng-options directive

Comment: thank you for your comments, in the end it was a scope issue, because the dropdown was inside of element that was created by a directive, it had a different scope and missing the menu property